# what is meaning that "reductive trapping" in organic chemstry?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Reductive trapping of intermediates, producing alkylated pyrroles, can be synthetically useful.

Comment: can you give more context? I suspect it means reducing an imine to an amine, which is no longer susceptible to hydrolysis, but there isn't enough info to be sure. In that case, you would react pyrrole with an aldehyde and then use mild reducing conditions to reduce the resulting imine without reducing the pyrrole ring.

Comment: Condensations of pyrroles with aldehydes and ketones occur easily by acid catalysis, but the resulting pyrrolyl - carbinols cannot usually be isolated, for under the reaction conditions proton - catalysed loss of water produces 2 - alkylidene - pyrrolium cations that are themselves reactive electrophiles. Thus, in the case of pyrrole itself, reaction with aliphatic aldehydes in acid inevitably leads to resins, probably linear polymers. Reductive trapping of these cationic intermediates(2-alkylidene pyrrolium cations), producing alkylated pyrroles, can be synthetically 
useful...

Comment: How to understand “reductive trapping” in the sentence above

Comment: Okay, it's the 2-alkylidene pyrrolium that is reduced to a 2-alkyl pyrrole rather than N-alkylidene to N-alkyl.

Answer (score 1):

In the presence of acid, the 2 position of pyrrole is nucleophilic and can attack electrophilic carbonyls such as aldehydes and ketones. The resulting carbinol (structure 1 in the scheme below) readily dehydrates to the 2-alkylidene pyrrolinium (2), which is itself quite electrophilic. As a result, it can be attacked by other pyrrole molecules (as happens in the Rothemund reaction, for example). To prevent this, compound 2 is reduced as shown in the scheme to yield a much less reactive 2-alkyl pyrrole. The 2-substituted compound is thus "trapped" by the reduction to prevent its further reaction.

[image: Reaction scheme]